# GLM predictor external to data frame is not found when data frame is specified

Tags: r, glm

I'm having trouble building a `glm.nb` object using the `MASS` package (though I have the same problem with a regular GLM too). The response and most of the predictors in the formula are columns in `data.daily`, but `cb` is a crossbasis object computed using the `dlnm` package.

My understanding of [`glm()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3.1/topics/glm) is that formula components are first searched for in the context of the object specified with `data`, and then in the environment that the formula is in. The formula (`glm.formula`) and `cb` are in the same environment, but `glm()` is reporting that `cb` can't be found. What's going on here?

```
Browse[1]> glm.obj = glm.nb(glm.formula, data = data.daily)
Error during wrapup: object 'cb' not found

Browse[1]> environment(glm.formula)
NULL

Browse[1]> environment(cb)
NULL

Browse[1]> glm.formula
[1] "count_admitted ~ offset(log(pop)) + nowork + cb"

Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "cb"          "data.daily"  "glm.formula" "glm.list"    "pred.list"
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'm calling `glm.nb()` from within a loop, whereas `cb` is calculated before the loop starts, but my understand of scope in R is that braces do not create a new scope—only functions.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't append `cb` to `data.daily` as a column?

Comment: I'd assumed that only vectors could be attached as columns, but it turns out that that's not the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can combine external vectors with `data.frames` specified as data in the same model. Try:

```
 glm.nb(glm.formula, data = cbind(cb = cb, data.daily))
```

This attaches the column to the data.frame.

Comment: I don't know... the [dlnm vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlnm/vignettes/dlnmOverview.pdf) suggests it can be done this way :/ Also, cb is not a vector, so I can't attach it to the data frame. My current workaround is to copy the data frame columns to the current environment, but with thousands of models to fit, this isn't too appealing :(

Comment: My bad—the crossbasis is a matrix of the same length as my time series by  12 wide.  I assumed only vectors could be attached!

Comment: I'll wait until I've finished my run to confirm this answer to make sure I haven't introduced any nasty bugs, but thanks a lot :D

Comment: The vignette you attached also uses `cb` as the sole source of dependent variables in a `lm`. As your formula is more complex I am unsure what the effect might be. Good luck, let us know how it goes.